# Flattening nested subscribes

Tags: angular, rxjs

Given the following:

```
this.activatedRoute.parent.params
  .subscribe(params => {
    let fooId = +params['fooId'];

    this.activatedRoute.params
      .subscribe(params => {
        let barId = +params['barId'];

        this.fooBarService.getFooBars(fooId, barId)
          .subscribe(fooBars => {
            this.fooBars = fooBars;
          });
      });
  });
```

Part of the nesting can be simplified with the following:

```
this.activatedRoute.parent.params
  .subscribe(params => {
    let foo = +params['fooId'];

    this.activatedRoute.params
      .switchMap(params => this.fooBarService.getFooBars(fooId, +params['barId']))
      .subscribe(fooBars => {
        this.fooBars = fooBars;
      });
  });
```

But is it possible to flatten the remaining nested subscribe?

Comment: Use the combineLatest operator

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet that did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the combineLatest operator:

```
Observable
  .combineLatest(this.activatedRoute.parent.params, this.activatedRoute.params)
  .switchMap(data => this.fooBarService.getFooBars(+(data[0])['fooId'], +(data[1])['barId']))
  .subscribe(fooBars => {
    this.fooBars = fooBars;
  });
```